# How to use Vue-plugin-load-script

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to load a custom JS file into my vue and I recently came across vue-plugin-load-script and installed it. I configured it as below:

In my main.js I have

```
Vue.loadScript("file.js").then(() => {
  console.log("SUCESS")
}).catch(() => {
  console.log("FAILED")
})
```

however, the npm page does not show how to use your functions in your views. For instances, lets say the file.js had a function called calculateTime(), and I have a view called Home.vue. How would I call the calculateTime() function from my

```
<script>
   export default {
    methods : {
       ** Trying to put function here **
     }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have you JS File local, you can import it, like:

```
import * as localA from "./../../theFile.js"; /*put your path to file.js*/
```

And after that you can use all methods from theFile.js by writting in a method from your vue Component

```
methodVue: function (...) {  
  localA.theMethod(param); /*the Method is declared in theFile.js*/    
  return;
}
```

And in your theFile.js your method that you want to use need to be written like that

```
export function theMethod(param) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a specific reason to use this library? Looking at the function all it does is add a `script` tag to the DOM if it is not already there and resolve the promise when it loads [GitHub link](https://github.com/tserkov/vue-plugin-load-script/blob/master/index.js). You could just as well use `import * from 'file.js'` at the top of the vue file. Then use the functions from that file as usual. The bundler should be able to figure out if the file is imported in multiple places and add it only once.

Comment: what if the file is remote, still how do you call the methods from the remote file?